# ES6 in plain javaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to transform this snippet to plain javaScript:

```
Meteor.startup(() => {
    if (!Meteor.users.findOne({name: 'anything'})) {
        let id = Accounts.createUser({
            username: 'admin',
            email: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
        });
    }
});
```

I think I have to transform the first line...

Comment: The first line is anonymous function

Comment: I think he means arrow function... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions a function with no arguments requires parentheses.

Comment: For future ES6 => ES5 needs, I recommend https://babeljs.io/repl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to change the function definition and not use `let`.
There is no sign of a `this` in your code snippet, but note that `this` differs between `=>` and `function`.

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
    if (!Meteor.users.findOne({name: 'anything'})) {
        var id = Accounts.createUser({
            username: 'admin',
            email: 'admin',
            password: 'admin'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could change it up a little bit like:

```
 Meteor.startup(function() {
if (Meteor.users.find().count() == 0){
       Accounts.createUser({
        username: 'admin',
        email: 'admin',
        password: 'admin'
       });
    }

}
```